# Custom sumif function for all sheets in workbook - Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a function in google scripts that applies a sumif over all sheets except the first one (as it works as a summary sheet). In other words, I want the same function to run on multiple sheets and on each sheet perform a sumif function. This is cause the condition column can be in any order and the number of sheets are ever growing. Here is the code I'm trying to use to accomplish the task.

Cond = The name to lookup (string),
Range = Range where the name (first column) and the value is located,
Col= Which column contains the value to sum (aka if range is A:B and the name is A then Col should be 2)

```
function sumIfAllSheets(cond,range,col) {
  var sheet = []
  var values = []
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < sheets.length ; i++ ) {
      sheet = sheets[i];
      values = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();

      for (var j in values) {
        if (typeof(values[j][0]) == 'number' && values[j][0] == cond) {
          sum += values[j][col-j];
        }   
      }
    }

  Logger.log(sum)
    return sum;
}
```

For some reason it only evaluates to 0. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!